# Ordering of Fields with Map in Avro Schema

Tags: jackson, schema, avro

Is it possible to have the fields within a map in Avro schema to be in a definitive order. I tried using the `JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetical=true)` annotation in the `avdl` but it seemed to have no affect on the fields in the map.

PS. I'm not talking about sorting the records according to some field. Example expected output of printing a map with five fields should be

```
            "params": {
                "map": {
                    "a_param": {
                        "int": 10
                    },
                    "b_param": {
                        "int": 10
                    },
                    "c_param": {
                        "int": 10
                    },
                    "d_param": {
                        "int": 10
                    },
                    "e_param": {
                        "int": 100
                    }
                }
            }
```

i.e. All the fields within the map are sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any clearly-defined mechanism in the standard that allows for what you want.  If all the potential map keys are known beforehand, you might consider changing your map to a record-- where the field order is defined-- and making their field type a union type of ["null", "int"], to account for missing values.

If you really need to customize how the JSON looks though, the Avro schema is probably the wrong place to do it.  I don't know where or how the output is being used or I would make suggestions.